# How to read property names and its value which are in single quotes in File1.txt and find that property name and value in File2.txt

Tags: batch-file, text-files

How to read property names, (ex: `SysValidate#URL`) and its value from single quotes, `'/api/sys/test'`, in `File1.txt` and find that property name and value in `File2.txt`.

**File1.txt**

```
Wed 11/08/2023 - 13:47:58.42 
BIP1138I: Applying overrides using runtime baroverrides...
BIP1140I: Overriding property SysValidate#URL with '/api/sys/test' in 'app_flow/META-INF/broker.xml' ...
BIP1140I: Overriding property SystValidate#Sendemail with 'TRUE' in 'app_flow/META-INF/broker.xml' ...
BIP1140I: Overriding property API_Analytics#username with 'testUser' in 'app_flow/META-INF/broker.xml' ...
BIP1140I: Overriding property API_Analytics#password with 'testPassword#' in 'app_flow/META-INF/broker.xml' ...
BIP1140I: Overriding property API_Analytics#realm with 'provider' in 'app_flow/META-INF/broker.xml' ...
```

In a line there can be multiple single quotes, but only the first single quotes need to be taken.

**File2.txt**

```
Wed 11/08/2023 - 13:47:59.43 
BIP1052I: Reading Bar file using runtime mqsireadbar...
SysValidate#URL = /api/sys/test
SystValidate#Sendemail = TRUE
API_Analytics#username = analytics
API_Analytics#password = Trustmark2021#
API_Analytics#realm = provider/default-idp-2
```

I'm using the following, but it is just picking the value, not the property name.

```bash
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("C:\Users\k2\File1.txt") DO FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO (
 SET "word=%%y"
 IF "!word:~0,1!!word:~-1!"=="''" (
 ECHO Processing %%y
  FIND "!word:~1,-2!" "C:\Users\k2\File2.txt">nul
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>"C:\Users\k2\Results.txt" ECHO %%y - Failed) ELSE (>>"C:\Users\k2\Results.txt" ECHO %%y - Success)
 )
)
```

Comment: In the batch file can be used: `for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims='" %%I in ("%USERPROFILE%\File1.txt") do %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%%I" "%USERPROFILE%\File2.txt" >nul && echo Found in File2.txt: '%%I'|| echo File2.txt does not contain: '%%I'` If that output should be written into a file, use `(for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims='" %%I in ("%USERPROFILE%\File1.txt") do %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%%I" "%USERPROFILE%\File2.txt" >nul && echo Found in File2.txt: '%%I'|| echo File2.txt does not contain: '%%I') >"%USERPROFILE%\Results.txt"`

Comment: Open a command prompt window, run `for /?` and read the output usage help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. Run next `find /?` and read the short output help. See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the two conditional command operators `&&` and `||` as used here for efficient evaluation of the result (exit code) of __FIND__.

Comment: Hello @Mofi, thank you for the helping. I have tried your logic mutiple times and it found some 30 values in file2.txt and the script stopped working I have to ctrl-c to exit script since it was doing nothing. I have around 100 properties in both file1.txt and file2.txt. Below is logoic, did I mess up anything?
```(FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims='" %%I IN ("C:\Users\k2\File1.txt") DO %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%%I" "C:\Users\k2\File2.txt" >nul && ECHO Found in File2.txt: '%%I'|| ECHO File2.txt does not contain: '%%I') >>"C:\Users\k2\Results.txt"```

Comment: Did you run the batch file from within a command prompt window to see the error message output by `cmd.exe` caused by a syntax error during the execution? I see that you have `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in the batch file. Replace that command line by `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` which is the Windows default. The enabled delayed variable expansion is problematic for the command line posted by in case of the string read from `File1.txt` and assigned to loop variable `I` contains characters with a special meaning for `cmd.exe` like `&` or `!`.

Comment: It would be more safe using twice `"%%I"` instead of `'%%I'` which of course results in writing the double quotes also into `Results.txt`. But delayed variable expansion should be nevertheless not enabled during execution of the __FOR__ command line to prevent a modification of the executed commands by the string read from `File1.txt` during the loop iterations. Delayed variable expansion is disabled by Windows default for good reasons and should be used wisely in a batch file processing strings of unknown consistence.

Comment: Did you saw my answer below?

Comment: @Mofi: Thank you for the all the help. Solved my problem.

Comment: @Aacini: Thank you for another approach, your solution worked out too.

Comment: I suggest you to compare _the time_ that both methods takes... Your approach execute the `find.exe` file once per each line in File1.txt. My solution should be faster...

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load property values from File2.txt
for /F "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('findstr "=" File2.txt') do set "property[%%a]=%%b"

rem Process File1.txt
for /F "tokens=4,6" %%a in ('findstr "property" File1.txt') do (
   echo Property %%a = %%b
   if defined property[%%a] (
      echo     in File2 = !property[%%a]!
   ) else (
      echo     not defined in File2
   )
)
```

Output:

```
Property SysValidate#URL = '/api/sys/test'
    in File2 = /api/sys/test
Property SystValidate#Sendemail = 'TRUE'
    in File2 = TRUE
Property API_Analytics#username = 'testUser'
    in File2 = analytics
Property API_Analytics#password = 'testPassword#'
    in File2 = Trustmark2021#
Property API_Analytics#realm = 'provider'
    in File2 = provider/default-idp-2
```